# How do you access a randomly generated event in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have data that was pulled from a spreadsheet in my database as a bunch objects. That bit looks like this
[image: Events section of my database]

Then, I have my users stored over here with their usernames and any events they're associated with

[image: Users section of my database]

I'm trying to access the events that the user is associated with, but the title of the events is randomly generated by Firebase. How do I call that specific one if I don't know what it's called? I now realize that this is also going to be an issue when trying to call to get any data from the events.

Comment: This section of the docs may help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: Yea, that doesn't really help me access that data though. Thanks for trying to help though :D

Comment: Well my thought was that you could restructure it to be easy to access the way you want. But I don't know if you have control over that, or want to go through the work of it

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I should restructure?

Comment: Instead of having the randomly generated IDs, you could make the event IDs just an incrementing number. The users' ID could be the username itself, since that should be unique anyways. In case you haven't seen it yet, [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data) tells you how to set your own data without the random stuff

Comment: I would then also have to have a way to keep track of how many events I have. Should I create another section in the database that is just to keep track of the count of events? Or is there some way to see the number of objects in a certain section. (I.E: How many events there are in the event category)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116835/discussion-between-chris-martinez-and-mjr).